# If $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,2\}$, what is $A \cup B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,2\}$, what is $A\cup B$? The empty set?

---

So if for all sets A and B, if $A \cup B = \emptyset$, then $A=\emptyset$? If not, how to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What elements are in at least one of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: confused, empty set or {1,2} ?

Comment: 1 is in at least one of $A$ and $B$, and 2 is in at least one of $A$ and $B$ too

Comment: You should **really** review the definitions of union, the empty set, and generally the use of "for all" quantifiers.

Comment: Is this kind of question allowed here? It is misleading, and its resolution lies in book definitions the author could have easily looked up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The union $\cup$ of two sets is the set containing every element that is in A, as well as every element that's in B. We pool the elements, and throw out duplicates:

$$A\cup B = \{1, 2\}$$

The union of two sets $$ A\cup B = \varnothing \iff A = \varnothing\;\;\text{AND}\;\; B = \varnothing$$

Let $A \cup B = \varnothing$. Suppose $A \neq \varnothing$. Then there exists at least one $a \in A$. We know that $A \cup B$ contains any and every element that appears in $A$ or appears in $B$, or both. So, since $a \in A$, $a \in A\cup B$. But then by definition, $A\cup B$ cannot be empty! But this contradicts $A \cup B = \varnothing$. Hence, $A = \varnothing$. By symmetry, the same holds for $B = \varnothing.$

Comment: Thanks amWhy, you are the man!

Comment: @rMath:  *she* is the (wo)man ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

**HInt:** What is the definition of $\cup$?

Comment: updated my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, try to prove that if $A\subseteq\emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$. Then try to use that.